# Firefox laggs on transition effect

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, transition

I have kept the main of what my page contain:
http://boxfly.free.fr/test/transition

So, we can choose to the top right the number of boxes which will be displayed, and unfortunately from only 2 boxes Firefox lags when we click on "Click Here to move the div"

CSS:

```
 #DivWraper {
     transition: margin-left 0.5s ease-in; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
 }
 #DivWraper.openSidebar {
     margin-left: 250px;
 }
```

JS:

```
 $("#LinkChange").click(function() {
     if($("#DivWraper").hasClass("openSidebar")) {
         $("#DivWraper").removeClass("openSidebar");
     } else {
         $("#DivWraper").addClass("openSidebar");
     }
 });
```

With Chrome the transition effect is all the time fluid, even with 50 boxes displayed.

How can I optimize this effect to make it fluid with Firefox too?

Answer (score 1):

You can use translate on movable div to give it some hardware boost.

```
`transform: translateZ(0);`
```

Comment: Where should I add transform? On `#DivWraper` like that: `#DivWraper { 
transition: margin-left 0.5s ease-in;
transform: translateZ(0);
}` ?

Comment: @LondonSmith yes, exactly.

Comment: I updated the CSS and I don't see any difference: http://boxfly.free.fr/test/transition/index-translateZ.html

Answer (score 0):

Someone from the Mozilla foundation has opened a bug ticket:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1373394

It's due to the activation of the multiprocess (e10s). To check the difference, desactivate e10s by:

about:config

browser.tabs.remote.autostart=false

browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2=false